# AlertDialog.Builder in onCreateDialog() not working properly

Tags: android, dialog

I'm implementing a dialog with a `ViewPager` using `DialogFragment` (v4). Everything works well except when I tried to add the title, positive button and negative button to the dialog.

Here's what I did:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("修改时间...")
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_setDatetime_positiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_setDatetime_negativeButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

(just ignore the Chinese characters since they don't make any differences I think.)

The result is, the title and buttons were not shown. It seems that `AlertDialog.Builder` doesn't work properly or I did something wrong?

Tested on Nexus 5 running Lollipop.

Edit: If I call `builder.create()` and return the dialog, I will get the error message:

`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: use `builder.create().show()`

Comment: To @Apurva: `builder.create().show()` doesn't return a dialog. How to deal with the return value?

Comment: replace `getActivity()` by `YourActivityName.this` in `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());`

Comment: you should try zil mike's answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call builder.create() and then return the dialog.

Comment: A runtime exception will be thrown if I call builder.create(). Actually I used create() first, met the problem, and found a solution to avoid it by calling show() instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like below.(Just ignore the Chinese characters)

```
void exit() {

    Dialog noticeDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("确定退出？ ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("退出", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AppManager.getAppManager().AppExit(SettingActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("取消", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    noticeDialog = builder.create();
    noticeDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: A runtime exception will be thrown if I call builder.create(). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("title")
            .setPositiveButton("Positive button",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //process the positive button click event
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Negative button",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //process the negative button click event
                        }
                    }
            )
            .create();
}
```